# Print Div ID html content Server side

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I developed a webpage where I want to send visitors geolocation to my Email via smtp. Currently Geolocation is properly implemented and map is displayed to me with longitude and latitude. 
Map is displayed via div id. I want to send that to code behind to send email. Below is my code implementation.

```html
<head runat="server">
   <title>Get User Current Location using Google Map Geolocation API Service in asp.net website</title>
   <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC6v5-2uaq_wusHDktM9ILcqIrlPtnZgEk&sensor=false"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
      } else {
          alert("Geo Location is not supported on your current browser!");
      }
      function success(position) {
          var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
          var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
          var city = position.coords.locality;
          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
          var myOptions = {
              center: myLatlng,
              zoom: 12,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              title: "lat: " + latitude + " long: " + longitude
          });
      
          marker.setMap(map);
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "<b>User Address</b><br/> Latitude:" + latitude + "<br /> Longitude:" + longitude + "" });
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div runat="server" id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
   </form>
</body>
```

```
//Code behind

// Gmail Address from where you send the mail
var fromAddress = "abc@gmail.com";
// any address where the email will be sending
var toAddress = "xyz@gmail.com";
//Password of your gmail address
const string fromPassword = "abxskc";
//string IP = map_canvas.Text;
var myDiv =  map_canvas.InnerHtml += "test";
// Passing the values and make a email formate to display
string subject = "GEO LOC".ToString();
string body = "GEOLOC: " + myDiv + "\n";
// smtp settings
var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
{
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
smtp.Timeout = 30000;
}
// Passing values to smtp object
smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
```

Comment: What I would suggest is moving the div#map_canvas outside of the server form. And on the server form add 2 inputs( text, hidden ) and set the value to those from the js myLatlng variable.

Comment: sorry i didn't got you. Can u write the code